# PayPal Rest API Get Capture by Id internal server error 500

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been having this issue lately when trying to get a completed capture by the capture ID and received internal server error 500. 
It's been a hit or miss, some captures returns back fine and a lot of time it would throw exception when I call Capture.Get(ApiContext, captureId);

Here are a couple debug id:

82e5f57da64a0

3a8dcfc41f6b9

Please help thanks!

Comment: more info on the debug {PROXY_SERVER_INFO: host=slcsbplatformapiserv3002.slc.paypal.com;threadId=438
Paypal-Debug-Id: 804851c31983d,804851c31983d
CORRELATION-ID: 804851c31983d
}

Comment: I have some more debug id if someone can check Production
orderid=O-57799332L04910905
[captureid=36B85166MW4215704] {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"47ac1c95e4cc6"}

Sandbox
captureid=1E50449143504691V {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"b8cc37c6855c0"}
captureid=3HJ48422XS4574343 success
captureid=2PK58768GG4511433 success
captureid=1RA023584T216433K {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"c6927c6477bc"}